Motivation for group homology
I am studying homology of groups and i need to make a motivation part in a seminar, that is not only of algebraic topology then many people wouldn't have heard of this before.
My motivation was to learn Homological stability (Quillen's approach) but i need something to tell that can be introduce with less preliminaries or that is clear without deep knowledge of the area. So far i have:

Proving that a group is not free: For example the fundamental group of surfaces of genus n, because if it were free then the homology of degree 2 and above would be $0$.

And i trying to find more things like this with a brief explanation. For example, seeing properties of a group such as, if a group is abelian, finite, of finite/infinite index or what is it's commutator. (it can also be something that is not in this list and does not need to be a proposition that works for all groups).

It is a bit easier to justify group cohomology by appealing to group-theoretic applications (classification of semidirect product and central extensions using $H^1$ and $H^2$ respectively). Ditto topological applications.

Also, have you read a textbook on this subject or how did you learn it? For instance, one of the standard references is Brown's "Cohomology of groups" where in the introduction he explains why these are interesting and useful.

@MoisheKohan I am actually following that book but i don't find that the motivations of the introduction are what I'm looking for (maybe I didn't understand them well)

Then, without you explaining better what is it that you are looking for, your question is unanswerable. In particular, you should explain why Brown's motivation for group (co)homology does not work for you. Maybe it was a mistake to agree to present material  that you do not understand well.

It is a undergraduate presentation of one's first approach to investigation, since the whole idea is to study something that you don't understand. The people attending know that and won't use it without verifying it and i don't see the point in your comment if you don't want to answer it don't do it, there are answers to this if it isn't a single one it doesn't mean that there are none.

in this point i can accept motivations for homology of spaces too

From what you wrote, it seems that your audience consists of people who do not know much algebra (maybe just basic group theory) and topology (maybe just the definition of a topological space and a homeomorphism, but maybe not even that). To such audience, it is pretty much hopeless to talk about uses of homological algebra in group theory since it would require too much background. Nevertheless, you can try to explain that the 2nd cohomology group (which you would treat as a black box without defining its meaning) $H^2(G,A)$ classifies extensions of a group $G$ by an abelian group $A$ of the form
$$
1\to A\to E \to G\to 1,
$$
i.e. $G\cong E/A$. Here the given information is a homomorphism $\phi: G\to Aut(A)$. This relation between the 2nd cohomology and group extensions is complicated and is explained in Brown's book. Why is cohomological approach useful? Because it allows one to use some topological methods to show, for instance, that  there is only one such extension, namely the semidirect product
$$
A\rtimes_\phi G
$$
This is an example of how topology applies to algebra.
You can also explain that the basic idea behind algebraic topology is to use algebra to solve topological problems. You can find many examples of such applications in standard algebraic topology textbooks, for instance, in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology."
Here are few examples. First, remind everybody of the intermediate value theorem. One way to state it is to say that if $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function such that $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$, then $f$ takes all the values in the interval $[0,1]$. Then you ask if this result generalizes to continuous vector-functions of several variables. You then state
Theorem. Suppose that $B$ is the closed unit ball (centered at $0$) in $\mathbb R^n$ and $f: B\to \mathbb R^n$ is a continuous function which is the identity map on the boundary sphere of $B$. Then $B\subset f(B)$. In particular, the equation $f(x)=0$ has a solution
$x\in B$. Then you sketch a proof using some basic facts about $n-1$-st homology groups.
You can also talk about Brouwer's fixed point theorem at this point, since it is proven as an application.
Then you can ask your audience if somebody can prove that $\mathbb R$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, $n\ge 2$. This can be done with bare hands, using the notion of a connected space. But then ask about, say, $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^4$ and explain why these are not homeomorphic using 2nd homology groups.
If you still have time left, you can talk about persistent homology and its applications to the data science.
The caveat is that you have to know the material that I suggested. I have no idea if you do.

Group (Co-)homology yields a very rich approach to Number Theory. Here is a concrete example:
Let $L/K$ a Galois extension with Galois group $G$. Then $G$ acts on the multiplicative group $L^\times$, turning it into a $G$-module.
Generalised Hilbert 90: $H^1(G,L^\times)=0$.
The classical Hilbert 90 theorem is a direct consequence of this. There are tons of other results from Number Theory, like the Kronecker-Weber Theorem that can be proven with the help of Group (Co-)homology.

If you've studied finite groups you've hopefully studied their representation theory of groups on complex vector spaces. (If you haven't seen representation theory of finite groups, you should skip the rest of this answer and also all your other plans for the week and go read the first few chapters of Serre's book on it.)
A fundamental result is that in particular a finite group has a finite special set of irreducible representations, and every other representation is a direct sum of those. This result, which only relies on an averaging trick, is also true if we just look at rational vector spaces (although an irreducible representation may decompose as a sum of smaller representations after extending scalars from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{C}$).
I hope you have seen representation theory before and are convinced it's useful for understanding groups (principally because linear algebra is easier than group theory and representation theory is a bridge between the two subjects). For example, even if you only care about the classification of finite groups and don't find representation theory intrinsically interesting, Burnside's theorem is most easily proved by representation theory.
So I think you should be convinced, no topology or geometry necessary, that it might be a good idea to generalize representaiton theory to actions of groups on abelian groups, but the "averaging trick" immediately fails since we can't divide by the order of the group. Moreover, the category of abelian groups, even if you want to stick to finitely generated ones, is much less well behaved than the category of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces.
For example, let $\{1, \tau\}$ be the group of order $2$. It acts on $\mathbb{Z}$ by having $\tau$ act as multiplication by $-1$ and $1$ act like the identity. This action sends the subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}$ to itself, and therefore we get an action on the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. But something weird happens: the class of $\overline{1}$ in the quotient is fixed by the action, even though there are no fixed points of the action but $0$ in either $\mathbb{Z}$.
Things like this don't happen in old-fashioned representation theory: the fixed vectors in a quotient representation lift to fixed vectors in the original representation -- this is a consequence of our "fundamental result."
This failure of fixed points to lift to other fixed points is measured by group cohomology: if $M \subset N$ are $G$-module, then there is a map from the $G$-fixed vectors in $N/M$ to the cohomology group $H^1(G, M)$ and the kernel of this map is the vectors that lift to $G$-fixed vectors of $N$. (Homology is also useful, but the "fixed points" are a bit easier to think about than the "co-invariants.")

Love the answer, i will definitely read what you recommend.
